# Searching the mode inside of a numpy array by region

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following `numpy` array with a first row which contains information related to a region, and a second row which is the value obtained in each of this regions:

```
[[1,2,2,3,4,5,5,3,3,3],[2,1,1,4,3,2,2,4,4,1]]
#                                         |this value has to be changed to the most frequent
```

I'm trying to obtain the mode of values per region, in order to have the most frequent value of each region, as following:

```
[[1,2,2,3,4,5,5,3,3,3],[2,1,1,4,3,2,2,4,4,4]]
#                                         |in this case the most frequent is 4
```

In the previous example the last region changed its value to 4 because is the most frequent value of this region. Do you have any suggestion about how can be done without use an iteration?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: By region do you mean sequence of identical values or just identical values? Like in first row, you have 3 at 4th position and then last three 3s. So, is that first 3 part of that region or a separate one?

Comment: Just identical values. All the 3s are part of the same region.

Comment: Do you consider a pandas solution?

Comment: Yes, I don't have problems to use a pandas solution :D